# Extending The Reducibility of Binary Operators to Conjunctions, Disjunctions and Negations for 3 Propositions

Tags: logic

The statement of the theorem is as follows:

Let *o(p,q,r)* be a compound statement that depends on the primitive propositions *p* , *q* and *r*. Prove that there is a formula for *o* which consists solely of $\land$, $\lnot$ and 
$\lor$.

**My Approach:**

We know that propositions *p* and *q* can be logically connected using the three operators mentioned. In other words, any binary operator that connects them can also be reduced to a mixture of conjunctions, disjunctions and negations.

Now, *p* *o* *q* forms one proposition by itself. Let us call it *z*. Then, we have *z* *o* *r*, which forms another proposition. Since these two propositions are connected using a binary logical operator, we can reduce that to a mixture of conjunctions, disjunctions and negations. Since *z* was formulated as a mixture of conjunctions, disjunctions and negations, we conclude that the entire proposition can be represented as a mixture of conjunctions, disjunctions and negations. This concludes the proof.

I was wondering if my approach is correct and if it can be formulated in a better way. I’m guessing that ‘mixture of conjunctions, disjunctions and negations’ is not formal language in Logic.

Also, if we consider *n* different propositions, would the argument be the same? I have a strong feeling that it will be but, unfortunately, Math doesn’t operate on ‘strong feelings’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any $n$-ary propositional function (i.e., a function of propositional variables whose value depends only on the truth values of the propositional variables) can be expressed in terms of $\neg$, $\vee$ and $\wedge$. This is true for all $n \geq 1$ (there is nothing special about $n=3$.)

Basically, an $n$=ary propositional function is just a function from $n$-tuples of elements of $\{T, F \}$ to $\{T, F \}$. The proof that any such function is expressible in terms of $\neg$, $\vee$ and $\wedge$ is by induction on $n$.

In the case $n=1$, there are 4 functions from $\{T, F \}$ to $\{T, F \}$, expressible by $o(p) = p$, $o(p)=\neg p$, $o(p)= p \vee \neg p$ and $o(p)= p \wedge \neg p$.

For the inductive step, assume the result holds for $n$, and let $o(p_0, ..., p_n)$ be a propositional function of $n+1$ variables. Then $o(p_0, ..., p_n)$ can be written as: $$(p_0 \wedge o_1(p_1, ..., p_n)) \vee (\neg p_0 \wedge o_2(p_1, ..., p_n)).$$ Applying the inductive hypothesis to $o_1$ and $o_2$, we are done.

In fact, because $\vee$ is definable in terms of $\wedge$ and $\neg$, any $n$-ary propositional function can be expressed in terms of just $\neg$ and $\wedge$.

Extending this to $n=0$ requires us, of course, to introduce symbols such as $\top$ and $\bot$ into the language.

Comment: Ah, so my approach was essentially correct, assuming i’m understanding this correctly.

Comment: Yes, your approach was definitely along the right track.